# set status as publish while installing component in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

Is it possible to publish the module while installing?

I'm installing a module along with the component.I need to set the status of module as publish while installing the component.

I use the following code in `manifest.xml` file:

```
<modules>
    <module module="mod_custom" publish="true"/>

    // I also tried none of them work
    <module module="mod_custom" client="administrator" publish="true" />
</modules>
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Why would you want to automatically publish the module. 

Even module is published, you will have to waste your energy to give that a position to appear on webpage and maybe set some parameters

Answer (score 0):

In the install.php of your component, you could look for the id of the installed module in the #__extensions table and then add it to the modules table and publish it but...

1. Consider carefully if you are overstepping your responsibility. Are you 100% sure that **all** users who install the component/module will **want** to immediately publish the module?
2. What module position will you publish the module to? There is no guarantee that the template used is using any specific module positions

You can learn more about the install php file here: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file